# pyaudio how to play a wav while one is playing already?

Tags: python, pyaudio

For example, I want to be able to play a wav file but when the user presses say the space bar, that audio file terminates and a new one starts playing.

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried and ask a specific question about what you are trying to do. This comes off as a request for a tutorial and that will not go over well here. It might help to include what other libraries you're using, for example, how you are capturing keypresses.

Comment: You can try to use subprocess module